# How can i work my bluetooth app under api 19 and above api 19?

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have android app about bluetooth LE, its work under api 21 well. But it doestn work other api's.
How can i fix it? 
How can i run bluetooth app under api 19 and above api 19 with together (same apk) ?

Comment: its work all api levels but , it doestn work stabil above api 19?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
```

it will return the API level of the OS, the you can use

```
if( Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < value){

  // do something 
 }
else{
 // do something else
   }
```

Comment: i tried this way , it worked above api 21 but didnt work under this api level

Comment: apology, you need to fix the problem of, the code is just to tell you how to do it. you need to search for the reason why bluetooth app don't work above api 21. but can help search as well